# Loop giving error and adding wrong values from ArrayList to JTree

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, arraylist, jtree

Fixed the previous post.

everything seems to run fine apart from the if statement, it sometimes adds the wrong number to the wrong place and it gives an error.

The aim is to add two ArrayLists to a Jtree. Arraylist containing whole numbers like (1,2,3,4 etc) and the second containing double number like (1.1,1.2,2.1 etc).

I want to add the first array to the JTree, which i have managed to do. But i then want to add the second arraylist so thats it is a child of the first.

So that 1.1 and 1.2 are a child of 1 and 2.1 is a child of 2 etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Code is runnable.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TreeExample2 extends JFrame
{
    private JTree tree;

public TreeExample2()
{
    final ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayList<String> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    JPanel frameG1= new JPanel();
    arrayList.add("1");
    arrayList.add("2");
    arrayList.add("3");
    arrayList.add("4");

    arrayList2.add("1.1");
    arrayList2.add("1.2");
    arrayList2.add("2.1");
    arrayList2.add("4.1");

    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setTitle("JTree Example");
    this.pack();
    frameG1.setVisible(true);

    frameG1.setSize(500,500);


    frameG1.setLayout(null);


            JFrame frameG2 = new JFrame("Cell Tree");
            frameG2.setSize( 400, 900 );
            frameG2.setVisible(true);

            frameG2.setBackground( Color.gray );

            DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("cells");
            tree = new JTree(root);
            frameG2.add(tree);
            int i=0;
            //should through first array list and adds it to root
            for (int n =0; n<arrayList.size();) {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode cells = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(arrayList.get(n));

                root.add(cells);

                //should go through jtree elements
                Enumeration search = root.postorderEnumeration();
                while(search.hasMoreElements()){

                    //should compare each element to a 2nd array
                    //2nd array consists of double numbers like 1.1,1.2,2.1 etc
                    //so i split it before the "." so 1.1 is 1
                    //first array consists of whole numbers like 1, 2, 3
                    //want to make 1.1 child of 1 etc.

                    if (search.nextElement().toString().equals(arrayList2.get(i).toString().split("\\.", 2)[0])) {
                        DefaultMutableTreeNode NewCells = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(arrayList2.get(i));
                        cells.add(NewCells);

                        i++;

                    }

                }
                n++;
            }

}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new TreeExample2();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

At some point the value of the variable `i` is equal to `4`,  while `arrayList2.size()`  is also equal to `4`.  This causes the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Adding the following condition seems to solve the problem

```
while(search.hasMoreElements() && (i<arrayList2.size())){
```

Unrelated to your problem, you can write

```
for (int n =0; n<arrayList.size();n++)
```

instead of

```
for (int n =0; n<arrayList.size();) {
....
n++;
```

Comment: Thanks! that seems to have fixed the error. It still seems to be adding some of the arraylist2 to the wrong place. e.g. 1.1 will become a child of 1 but then 1.2 becomes a child of 2. Any idea?